# 'Antarabhava' existence between rebirth and the death

Tags: theravada, rebirth, pratityasamutpada

Does a state called "Antarabhava" an existence between death and rebirth exist?

Traditional Theravada sources, highly respected scholars and texts in Abhidhamma directly decline this as there is no such thing in the Dependant Origination. Arahat Moggaliputta Tissa Thero has also rejected this in the 3rd Buddhist Council.

Bhikkus who support the claim that "Antarabhava" exists takes examples from suttas such as [Tirokudda Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/pv/pv.1.05.than.html) the first few verses,
[Kutuhalasala Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn44/sn44.009.than.html) the last paragraph where Buddha states that a being who has left the present body but has not reborn in another body is sustained on craving (Tanha).

Comment: Looks like you've already answered your question.

Comment: Agreed. Just wanted to see if anyone had other answers but you may vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bhava means birth, arising. While the aggregates are arising, born, they are being (Bhava) and being conditioned.

[AN 3.47:1.6](https://suttacentral.net/an3.47/en/sujato#an3.47:1.6) SaṅkhataLakkhaṇaSutta:

> “Mendicants, conditioned phenomena have these three characteristics.
>
> What three?
>
> Arising is evident, vanishing is evident, and change while persisting
> is evident.
>
> These are the three characteristics of conditioned phenomena.”

**So, "existence between death and rebirth" is "present being (present being birth and not death) of  past death and future rebirth in succession".**

Aggregates never stop to condition their effects. Even AsaññaSattaBhramma still be immagined by many real conditioner and conditioned. They have present 17 Rūpa which being conditioned by past Karmma and themselves.

So, there are nowhere "blank" or "special" between death and rebirth. There are only  death and rebirth between death and rebirth.

Comment: How do you explain [Kutuhalasala Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn44/sn44.009.than.html)?: "Vaccha, when a being sets this body aside and is not yet reborn in another body, I designate it as craving-sustained, for craving is its sustenance at that time."

Comment: 15. “Good Gotama, at the time this body (flame) is laid down and the being is not born in another body, what is the supportive condition (wine blowing flame) that good Gotama points to?”

“Vaccha, at the time this body is laid down and the being is not born in another body, I say the supportive condition is clinging-craving.”. https://84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=18&item=799&items=2&eng=metta_e

Answer (score 2):

Most who are born in the human world will wait in a mind-made body waiting for a suitable place to be born. However it is not a birth or an existence.

You can learn more from this Noble Eight-Fold Path Meditation: https://youtu.be/vu0UZDb3gKk?list=PLk22Pmbx-cNPA_vMHe4G9LOZaPm8GGpM_&t=5790

However the goal here is to understand the suffering nature of bodily pain (i.e. the 'dukka' part in dukka, domanassa, soka, parideva)

Comment: nice answer & link; more of this clear information would also be helpful

Comment: If you are interested in learning more, please see the meditations listed here: https://visuddhimagga.info/Med_English_video.php

Note: It is very important to actually try the meditations and do them in the way explained. Then see the experience for your self. These are focused directly on Nibbana and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you for kindly appending the nice link to additional material!